# angular Validators.compose issue

Tags: angular

Hi i tried to learn angular and i got error when i tried to use validator and i got error :
*Cannot read property 'value' of null*

here is my components:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ControlGroup , Control, Validators, FormBuilder} from 'angular2/common';
import {CustomValidators} from './custom.validators4';

@Component({
selector    :   'contact',
templateUrl :   'app/form.template4.html'
})

export class FormComponent4{
form1 : ControlGroup;

constructor(fb : FormBuilder){
    this.form1 = fb.group({
        oldpass : ['', Validators.required],
        newpass : ['', Validators.required],
        repass  : ['', Validators.compose([ Validators.required , CustomValidators.retypeMatch ])]
    });
}



onSubmit(){
    this.form1.find('oldpass').setErrors({
        incorrect : true
    })
}
}
```

Here is my CustomValidators component for above:

```
import {ControlGroup} from 'angular2/common';

export class CustomValidators{

static retypeMatch(group : ControlGroup){

    var pass = group.find('newpass').value;
    var retype = group.find('repass').value;

    if(pass == '' || retype == '')
        return null;

    if(pass != retype)
        return {retypeMatch : true};

    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Please update angular :) `angular2/core` is too old version

Comment: Your validator is a validator for a ControlGroup, but you use it to validate a FormControl (repass). That makes no sense. And I second yurzui's advice. Don't learn angular with a beta version from one year ago. Learn it with the current, stable version (4.2).